Locally compact groupoid with range map restricted to isotropy groupoid is open
Suppose the action groupoid =⋉, where  is a locally compact group and 
a locally compact space is such that isotropy subgroups of H  are isomorphic to each other.
Can this be an example of a groupoid such that the range map restricted to its isotropy subgroupoid is open?
